# C# reflection and generic GetValue convertion

Tags: c#

if we have different fields,like

```
int a;
bool b;
float c;
```

then the following convertion have to be used when we get its value using reflection

```
a=(int)FieldInfo.GetValue(...);
b=(bool)FieldInfo.GetValue(...);
c=(float)FieldInfo.GetValue(...);
```

Is there a generic method to get the value so that a foreach iteration can be used?

```
foreach(FieldInfo info in type.GetFields())
{
   var v=(T)info.GetValue(...);
}
```

Comment: No, but take a look at `IConvertible`

Comment: Does anyone have any good idea? For details please see [Demo example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUy92y). It is modified from code provided by John Wu @John Wu

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to know an object's type unless you wish to store it in a type-specific variable. The type of a variable has to be declared at compile time (yes, even if it is declared with `var`, which is expanded by the compiler when you build). So even if you could write a generic method to return `GetValue` as a specific type, that isn't exactly useful in the scenario you describe, because you still have no idea what code to write to declare the variable you're going to put it into.

That being said, a generic method is pretty trivial to write:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T GetTypedValue<T>(this FieldInfo This, object instance)
    {
        return (T)This.GetValue(instance);
    }
}
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
bool someFlag = fieldInfo.GetTypedValue<bool>(instance);
int someNum = fieldInfo.GetTypedValue<int>(instance);
```

or (this generates identical IL code):

```
var someFlag = fieldInfo.GetTypedValue<bool>(instance);
var someNum = fieldInfo.GetTypedValue<int>(instance);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  We would like to assign the reflected value to the type specific property of Controls in UI. The method you given is equal to an obvious type conversion.  We can read the field type by `FieldInfo.FieldType` or `FieldInfo.FieldType.Name`. But, it is a Type class or a string class. we do not know how to make a conversion by this Type or string.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to cast or convert. Just pass the instance of `object` to `SetValue`. See [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N69FS2).

Comment: A very good website, thanks! a little changes have been made and your `SetValue` method will be invalide and a conversion is needed. Please see  [link]https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUy92y